# What will happen if two photons collide perpendicularly?

Tags: optics, photons, interference

Suppose there is an object placed at (-1,0) on x-axis. A light ray coming from it is observed by an observer somewhere on positive x-axis. In addition, a second object is placed somewhere on y-axis. The ray coming from second object will interfere with the ray coming from first object perpendicularly. What will happen according to the observer on positive x-axis? Should we take wave nature of light? Do the photons colliding perpendicularly exhibit something to the observer? Consider both cases that the light rays are coherent and incoherent.

Comment: Photons are bosons.  Bosons don't really collide in the same sense that fermions do.

Comment: Aha! Thanks but what will happen as seen by the observer?

Comment: How will an observer observe these photons as they pass by each other? (I don't think the title of your question actually matches the body of your question.  And this sounds like homework, not your own question.)

Comment: @BrandonEnright Photons interact with each other very weakly, with higher order terms so they cannot be considered in this framework. It is classical intererence patterns for coherent sources ,  http://digitalcommons.unl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1129&context=physicsfacpub spurious interference patterns for incoherent ones,

Answer (score 1):

Photon photon interaction, which is what a collision will mean, is practically non existent as it is [higher order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_physics)  and in the context of this question, light sources, non existent in reality. If we reach gamma ray energies then particles will be produced but this has nothing to do with this question.

There will be interference patterns as whenever coherent beams meet which are important for radio waves and [antenna interferences .](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/light/Lesson-3/Other-Applications-of-Two-Point-Source-Interferenc) Either constructive or destructive depending on the phases and positions and a pattern will appear. Incoherent beams will create noise, sometimes constructively and sometimes destructively interfering,